# How can I tell if I have permissions to delete a file with Qt5 without actually trying to delete it?

Tags: file, qt5, file-permissions

**Question**

I am looking for something that would fulfil the expected semantics of an imagined `isRemovable()` method in the [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html) class.

In `QFile` reference there is a [permissions()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#permissions) method mentioned that returns a set of flags [QFileDevice::Permission](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#Permission-enum) wich basically corresponds to file permissions. There is also [isReadable()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#isReadable) and [isWritable()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#isWritable) but how can I in a relatively portable way know with certainty that I would be able to remove (delete) a file without actually trying?

**Answer**

Short answers with short and simple source-code are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a file if you have permissions to write both to a file and to it's containing directory. So, the solution (which I've tested on Centos Linux) will be:

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(filepath);
QFileInfo dirInfo(fileInfo.path());
bool isRemovable = fileInfo.isWritable() && dirInfo.isWritable();
```

Comment: I would like to know how portablie this is. I am usually on some Linux variant so I guess this is fine in my case, but a comment on this for other users that use other O/Ses might be in place!